# How to call a Javascript function by android

Tags: javascript, android, onclick

I have a problem something about JS and Android.

I need to call a JS function `onclick` by Android.

Here is the code :

```
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link href="portrait-styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function callApp() {
            window.location  = 'ios:webToNativeCall';
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="IO08_01.png" />
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/test1" onclick="callApp()" class="fb2"></a>
</div>
```

How can I get data `ios:webToNativeCall` to pass it to android and use android call url. 
I know how to use only in IOS but I don't know how to use in android.

Comment: What you want to send return.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible by using Javascript , try something like this http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/10/call-javascript-inside-webview-from.html